# Unable to break out of a loop when i press x

Tags: java, loops, break

It works (not as I wanted, the loop breaks if there is any 'x' present in the text like 'asdx') if I set condition as c=='x' but not if I put it as s=="x" (so loop breaks only if I type a single x only)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStreamReader i = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    String z = "";
    boolean bool=true;
    while (bool==true) {
        int x = i.read();
        char c = (char) x;
        String s = Character.toString(c);
        z += s;
        if (s=="x") {
            bool=false;
        }
    }
    out.println(z);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `equals` to compare `String` values:

```
if(s.equals("x")){
  bool=false;
}
```

with `==` you compare the object references.

Comment: Why s=="x" doesn't works?